# how to create a divisible by method in ruby

Tags: ruby, fizzbuzz

i am currently studying ruby and your help would be much appreciated.

i am trying to display the below results in my terminal:

```
1
2
3 i am divisible by 3
4
5 i am divisible by 5
6 i am divisible by 3
7
8
9 i am divisible by 3
10 i am divisible by 5
11
12 i am divisible by 3
13
14
15 i am divisible by 3 and 5
16
17
18 i am divisible by 3
19
20 i am divisible by 5
```

i am unsure how to go about. I wrote the below code in my divisible.rb:

```
def count
  numbers = (1..20)
  numbers.each do |number|
    if number % 1 == 1
      puts "#{number}"
    elsif number % 3 == 0
      puts "#{number} i am divisible by 3"
    elsif number % 5 == 0
      puts "#{number} i am divisible by 5"
    elsif number % 3 == 0 && number % 5 == 0
      puts "#{number} i am divisible by 3 & 5"
    end
  end
end
```

but it outputs the below in the terminal:

```
irb(main):001:0> count
3 i am divisible by 3
5 i am divisible by 5
6 i am divisible by 3
9 i am divisible by 3
10 i am divisible by 5
12 i am divisible by 3
15 i am divisible by 3
18 i am divisible by 3
20 i am divisible by 5
=> 1..20
```

could one please kindly advise me on the right path

Comment: You output in your loop just the divisable numbers. If I understand you right, you also want to output non-divisable numbers. You can catch this with an `else` at the end of your very long `if`. Also, you need to test more complex conditions (like divisable by 3 and 5) before simple ones.

Comment: Actually, the output you show does not correspond to the code you posted. Since every number is divisable by 1, the test `number % 1` would catch every number, and you would never run into one of the other conditions. Please always make sure that the code you post, corresponds to the output you really see.

Comment: @user1934428 please, always make sure that what you want to write is correct. Just run `2 % 1`

Comment: @AlexGolubenko : Thank you, I was reading carelessly! The OP compared that against 1, not zero!

Comment: @ARTLoe : Sorry for the confusion: Actually, the `number % 1 == 1` would never catch anything, because every number is divisable by one, so this branch would never been taken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 3 steps to fix it

1. Remove 1st if statement,
2. You should move this: `elsif number % 3 == 0 && number % 5 == 0` to 1st step
3. Add `else puts number`

it should look like:

```
def count
  numbers = (1..20)
  numbers.each do |number|
    if number % 3 == 0 && number % 5 == 0
      puts "#{number} i am divisible by 3 & 5"
    elsif number % 3 == 0
      puts "#{number} i am divisible by 3"
    elsif number % 5 == 0
      puts "#{number} i am divisible by 5"
    else
      puts number
    end
  end
end
```

**UPD**

Let's add an explanation about these steps:

1st and 3rd steps:
Dividing by 1 always will return 0 as a result, so the first reason is a mistake in logic and the second one is as now we know that this always is 0 we don't need to check it one more time.

2nd step:
When we check for example `3` with `elsif number % 3 == 0` it will return true, so next if-statements wouldn't be checked, to fix it we should first add checking for `number % 3 == 0 && number % 5 == 0`

Thanks to @3limin4t0r, you are right it's always better to explain.

Comment: You might want to add some additional explanation. Why should those steps be done? What is the reason for removing the first *if*-statement? Why should `number % 3 == 0 && number % 5 == 0` be moved to the first step? What is the reason for adding the *else*-statement? It might not be obvious for OP.

Comment: @ARTLoe no problems :)

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, you could use the [Prime](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.5/libdoc/prime/rdoc/Prime.html) class from standard lib, this way:

```
require 'prime'

(0..30).each do |number|
  if [0, 1].include? number
    puts number
    next
  end
  if Prime.prime?(number)
    puts "#{number} is prime"
  else
    divisors = Prime.prime_division(number).map(&:first)
    puts "#{number} is divisible by " + divisors.join(" and ") if divisors.size > 1
  end
end
```